# sum of an array using recursion Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Looking for a way to solve this problem by recursing `sum()`. Right now, the code works, but I am supposed to call `sum()` more than once, and it should not mutate the input array.

```
var sum = function(array) {
    if(array.length === 0){
        return 0;
    }
    function add(array, i){
        console.log(array[i]);
        if(i === array.length-1){
            return array[i];
        }
        return array[i] + add(array, i+1);
    }
    return add(array, 0);
};
sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) //21
```

Comment: I believe what you (they) are looking for is `function sum(array) { return array.length ? array[0] + sum(array.slice(1)) : 0; }`

Comment: @Bergi that's a possible answer, but I don't believe a good answer should be taking copies of any part of the array

Comment: @Alnitak Why? It's not a requirement stated by the OP. It's a fairly basic problem designed to help the OP's understanding of recursion. Seeking the most efficient solution misses the point - compactness and clarity should be a better goal in this case.

Comment: @Alnitak: I think it's better (purer) than giving `sum` an extra optional parameter :-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A one-liner that meets all your requirements:

```
var sum = function(array) {
    return (array.length === 0) ? 0 : array[0] + sum(array.slice(1));
}

// or in ES6

var sum = (array) => (array.length === 0) ? 0 : array[0] + sum(array.slice(1));

// Test cases
sum([1,2,3]); // 6

var s = [1,2,3];
sum(s); // 6
sum(s); // 6
```

### Reasoning

- In a recursive call, you need to model your task as *reduction* to a base case. The simplest base case in this case is the empty array - at that point, your function should return zero.
- What should the reduction step be? Well you can model a sum of an array as the result of adding the *first* element to the `sum` of the remainder of the array - at some point, these successive calls will eventually result in a call to `sum([])`, the answer to which you already know. That is exactly what the code above does.
- `array.slice(1)` [creates a shallow copy of the array starting from the first element onwards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), and no mutation ever occurs on the original array. For conciseness, I have used [a ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Breakdown:

```
sum([1,2,3])
-> 1 + sum([2,3])
-> 1 + 2 + sum([3])
-> 1 + 2 + 3 + sum([])
-> 1 + 2 + 3 + 0
-> 6
```

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track, but consider that sum could take an optional second argument (that defaults to zero) that indicates the position to start summing from...

```
function sum(array, n) {
    n ||= 0;
    if (n === array.length) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return array[n] + sum(array, n + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `n ||= 0;` doing? Is it short for `n = n || 0` ?

Comment: @kidwon yes - alternatively use `if (n === undefined) n = 0;`

Comment: is `n || = 0` ES6? It's so useful

Comment: This is mixing of concerns. Your function is less reusable. `sum` should just do what it claims to do, namely adding something up. If you want to skip the first x elements, just slice the array before passing it to `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sumNumbersRecursively(input){
    if (input.length == 0){
        return 0;
    } else{
       return input.shift() + sumNumbersRecursively(input);
    }
}

console.log(sumNumbersRecursively([2,3,4]))
```

Comment: What advantage does that have over the accepted answer?  I see a significant disadvantage in that it destroys the array you're trying to sum.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the add function inside your sum function just inline the function and initiate with, 0 as a starting point, or optionally check the i variable for undefined and initialize it to 0!

```
var sum = function(array, i) {
    if(array.length === 0){
        return 0;
    }
  console.log(array[i]);
  if(i === array.length-1){
    return array[i];
  }
  return array[i] + sum(array, i+1);
};
console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],0)) //21
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

- you can use **.reduce()** method
- or perform a simple tail recursion

With **reduction**:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

//In our reduce, we will apply our sum function, 
//and pass the result as the next value
const res = array.reduce(sum);
```

With **recursion**:

```
function sumRec(array, acc = 0, index) {
    //We will update our accumulator, and increment
  // the value of our current index
  return index === array.length
  ? acc
  : sumRec(array, acc += array[index], ++index);
}

console.log(sumRec(array, 0, 0));
```

Personally, I find the first solution more elegant.

Comment: the first solution is indeed elegant, but it's not the recursion that the OP has been asked for.

Answer (score 0):

arr = [1,2,3,4]
sum = arr.reduce((acc, curr)=> acc+curr)

Comment: This doesn't use recursion  which the OP has asked for

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumArr(arr){
  if(arr.length>1){
    return arr.pop()+sumArr(arr);
  }else{
    return arr[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have to call **sum** more than once, then use the binary approach: split the array in half and recur on each piece.  When you get to a length of 1, return the single value.

Does this work for you?  I'm afraid I don't recall the JS syntax for array slices, so my recursion statement may be wrong in the details.

```
var sum = function(array) {
    if(array.length === 1){
        return array[0];
    }
    mid = array.length / 2
    return sum(array[0:mid-1]) + sum(array[mid:array.length-1])
};
sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) //21
```

Comment: there is no advantage to a binary approach - the number of recursive calls and additions is still `O(n)`.

Comment: also taking array slices means that the program uses a lot more memory than required

Comment: The advantage is that OP has a requirement to call sum more than once.  That's the only reason I used the binary approach.  Otherwise, taking advantage would require multi-threading, which would only bear fruit with very large arrays.