# Sum Numbers Between 1 and a Given Number Using Recursion - Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

Summing numbers between one and a given number without recursion is simple:

```
function sumNums (num) {
  let array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
console.log(sumNums(3));
```

> 6

But what I don't understand, is that when we're using **recursion**, it causes the "loop" to occur throughout *the entire function*.

So if we have a for-loop (or any loop) within a function that's using recursion, it will cause an error - right?

And I assume that we'll need an array of the integers in order to reduce them - So know how else can we create an array of integers between one and and a given number without using some sort of loop?

**EDIT**: A simpler way of adding integers between 1 and num without recursion:

```
function sumNums (num) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(sumNums(3));
```

No need to add the integers to an array and then reduce it. Just add them to an initializer variable instead.

Comment: Please post the code of the recursive function that you keep talking about.

Comment: Why are you creating an array at all? You could just add up the numbers directly.

Comment: Using a loop in a recursive function does not cause an error. Why would it?

Comment: Is each number is incremented by 1 from starting number to given number?

Comment: The key is that if you use recursion, you don't need a loop. You just pass in (current value + 1) to the next call of the function.

Comment: I don't see any recursion here -_-

Comment: I hate tasks, that force people to use an unfit method. There are plenty examples, where recursion makes sense. Here, it doesn't.

Comment: @VikasKeskar Yes

Comment: @CodeManiac That's why the question says *without recursion* before the code.

Comment: @ASDFGerte - that's why this smells of "professor" driven task vs. "I have to get this work done" task.

Comment: The sum of the numbers between 1 and n is n + the sum of the numbers between 1 and n-1.

Comment: Also the closed-form formula `n * (n + 1) / 2` is the correct way to compute the result.

Comment: Why do you need an array at all?

Comment: Re all comments above, the OP seems to be asking for "how to" not "should I" or "is there a better alternative". These comments are mostly irrelevant.

Comment: If want to directly calculate sum, then refer this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1842203

Comment: Here using recursion is not a wise choice, you should use iteration method as long as it is possible with iteration.

Comment: Perhaps this is _most_ relevant comment: OP, please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: you have your answer, but here another version where tail call optimization can occur: `function sum(num, total=0){ return num > 0 ? sum(num-1, total+num) : total; }`

Comment: @Thomas thanks, can you please create an answer below?

Comment: @HappyHands31 while you question is closed as duplicate it is not possible to add a new answer

Comment: @HappyHands31 I think tco is beyond the topic for this question. This comment was meant more like a teaser, and a direction, for you to dive deeper into recursions. I'd find it great if you would end up understanding why and how my function can be optimized by the engine in a way that the ones in the answers can't.

Comment: @bruno I see. Well, this question should not be a duplicate. The articles that are listed for where answers already exist for this question, are different from mine. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425581/sum-of-an-array-using-recursion-javascript) talks about summing an array, where an array is passed in as an argument. And [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549836/how-to-find-the-sum-of-all-numbers-between-1-and-n-using-javascript) talks about summing all integers between 1 and N, but it does not mention using recursion.

Comment: There is plenty of talk here about how I'm not showing any attempts at recursion in my initial code, but, since I'm trying to learn recursion, my attempt was so bad that I felt as though it wasn't even worth showing. Part of the issue here is that there's an easier way to sum all integers between 1 and N without using an array. And I have shown that in the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the value and if truthy return `n` plus the sum of `n - 1`.

```js
function sum(n) {
    return n && n  + sum(n - 1);
}

console.log(sum(3));
```

A more traditional approach take the handed over value and checks if the value is smaller than one and returns zero in this case, otherwise the result of the actual value plus the result of calling sum function with a decrement value.

```js
function sum(n) {
    if (n < 1) return 0;    // exit condition
    return n  + sum(n - 1); // return value plus result of recursive call
}

console.log(sum(3));
```

Comment: Why would this get a downvote? It's a working solution.

Comment: @Pointy probably because the base case is unnecessarily obfuscated. "truthy" is not what matters.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote, but I don't understand why it works. As @Bergi pointed out, there doesn't seem to be a traditional base case here (if-statement)? I'm just trying to learn the basics of recursion.

Comment: So `return n  + sum(n - 1)` ....If `n` is 3.....then we have `return 3 + sum(3 - 1)`, which equals `return 3 + sum(2)` So 5. Then `return 5 + sum(5 - 1)`, which equals `return 5 + sum(4)`, which equals 9....so I still don't really understand. How is that getting closer to the base case?

Comment: the first is `3 + sum(2)`, the second is `3` from first part and `2 + sum(1)` from the second call and the final one is `1 + sum(0)` which is `1`, then a the call before is `2 + 1` the the result before is `3 + 3`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sumNumsRecursive = num => num ? sumNumsRecursive(num - 1) + num : 0

console.log(sumNumsRecursive(3));
```

Comment: Please explain your answers